# Derving circuit equations for $RLC$ circuit such that order does not matter

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, capacitance, inductance

Can we derive the circuit equations for an $RLC$ circuit from first principles in a way that makes it clear that the order of circuit elements doesn't matter?

I understand conceptually why the order does not matter because it is a series circuit, but I would like to see why mathematically that the order of circuit elements doesn't matter.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: the sum operation is commutative and you sum voltages on every element in equation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve a series circuit, you solve a system of simultaneous equations: one saying that the sum of the voltage drops across all components is zero, and, for each component, an equation relating the voltage drop across it to the current ($V=IR$ for a resistor, $I=CV'$ for a capacitor, etc.).

If you reorder the components, it reorders the voltages in the sum, which makes no difference since addition is commutative, and it reorders the other equations, which makes no difference since the order of simultaneous equations doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks so much for your solution!